# Inner Join syntax in AWS glue Job

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am writing an AWS Glue job where I am querying data from 2 datasources (one. from RDS and other from S3)using inner join. Now, it's throwing an error at the JOIN step. I saw that there is some other syntax but I cannot figure out how to use in the existing query.
Kindly look at the query and let me know how to correct it.
Below is the code. Thanks

```js
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job
import time
import boto3

print(time.strftime('%X') + " Started")

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
spark_session = glueContext.spark_session
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark_session.sparkContext, spark_session)
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "matomo", table_name = "matomo_matomo_log_visit", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "myxp-prod", table_name = "myxp_livestream_settings", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("visit_last_action_time", "timestamp", "visit_last_action_time", "timestamp"), ("custom_dimension_1", "string", "custom_dimension_1", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("title" , "string" , "title" , "string"),("timezone", "string", "timezone", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")

## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "matomo", table_name = "matomo_matomo_site", transformation_ctx = "datasource1"]
## @return: datasource1
## @inputs: []
datasource1 =  glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type= "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://gevme-datalake/People"]}, format= "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasource1")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("idsite", "int", "idsite", "int"), ("main_url", "string", "main_url", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping2"]
## @return: applymapping2
## @inputs: [frame = datasource1]
applymapping2 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource1, mappings = [("userid", "string", "userid", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping2")


df = datasource0.toDF()
df1= datasource1.toDF()


print(time.strftime('%X')+": DataFrames Created")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("myxp_livestream_settings")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("AllPeople")

print(time.strftime('%X')+": TempView Created")

consolidated_df = spark.sql("""SELECT livestream.title,
                                livestream.timezone,
                                count(distinct people.peopleid)
                                FROM
                                myxp-prod.myxp_livestream_settings livestream
                                JOIN
                                AllPeople people
                                ON
                                livestream.id = people.projectid
                                Group By 
                                livestream.title, livestream.timezone""")
print(time.strftime('%X')+": Prod query executed")                          
                            

consolidated_dynamicframe = DynamicFrame.fromDF(consolidated_df.repartition(1), glueContext, "consolidated_dynamicframe")
print(time.strftime('%X')+": Prod results consolidated")

## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://gevme-datalake/Latest-Projects"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = consolidated_dynamicframe, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://gevme-datalake/MetadataExplanationTable/"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")

job.commit()
```

Comment: "myxp_livestream_settings" is the name of the TableView you created, but your SQL query is from "myxp-prod.myxp_livestream_settings".  Did you intend that?

Comment: `myxp-prod`  is the database name and inside that I have the table `myxp_livestream_settings`. That's why given the full path in the query.

Comment: Maybe try giving the view a unique name (myxp_livestream_settings_view) and joining on that.

Comment: Could you share the actual error message?